# Inverted Water Dispenser

Tags: pressure

My head is exploding thinking about this. Consider the water dispenser below. The upper bottle is squeezed and inverted. My question is, will it rebound gradually to its cylindrical form? Or will it abruptly rebound to its cylindrical form when the last bit of water is transferred to the bottom bottle?

[image]

Intuitively the answer seems to be gradual rebound. But I'm unable to wrap my head around how the pressure of water (indicated by level of water in upper bottle) is going to determine how much it will rebound? How is the pressure going to make a difference on the amount of air that will enter through the mouth?
Here are some more clarifications regarding the system:

1. Upper bottle is almost full. About 10% of the top of it is filled with air.
2. Bottom bottle is almost full too. Kindly [read up](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88669/physics-of-the-inverted-bottle-dispenser) about how inverted water dispenser system works. It's fairly simple.
3. Assume that the upper bottle is elastic enough to rebound immediately, when it's empty.

P.S. Contrary to how unhygeinic an impression this photo might be giving you, the water is pretty clean from the inside. I'm drinking it and I'm healthy too. Also, I'll find out the answer as this week progresses. But I want to understand the mechanics behind it.

Update: After a week, I realised this this bottle has been permanently deformed. Lol. I figure that if the elastic force that's trying to rebound the bottle is large enough to suck more water inwards, only then equilibrium will be reached.

Comment: The pressure of the air in the air pocket at the top of the inverted bottle will be a little bit less than the surrounding atmospheric pressure due to the weight of all of the water in the bottle, and that will put some stress on the bottle but these bottles are designed to handle those stresses and shouldn't crumple because of them. If you squeezed the bottle to crumple it then you did something extra for which it was not designed. No idea if it will rebound or not when all the water leaves it or whether the process will be gradual or not. You'll just have to see for yourself.

Comment: @SamuelWeir how is the weight of water going to affect the pressure in air pocket at the top?

Comment: The water in the bottle wants to move downward due to gravity. What's keeping it the bottle is the pressure difference between the atmospheric pressure outside the bottle and the pressure of the air pocket balancing out against the weight of the water.